# loggin into an iOS app using a system with ADFS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I am interested in making an app that logs into a system that uses Single Sign on with ADFS and SAML.

Now I am happy to read up on it, I just was wondering if there is anything out there that is specific to the iOS platform and how this integrates, maybe even with a demo app.

I have found this website:
[Single Sign-On for Desktop and Mobile Applications using SAML and OAuth](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth)

I do realise that this is not an "coding problem" question, but I am sure they will come out of this when I start developing:-)

I hope some of you are able to provide some helpful information on this:-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of ADFS (3.0, included in Windows server 2012 R2) has a feature called "workplace join". This can be used to join iPads etc. to active directory and get single sign on and storing a certificate on the iPad. [Here](http://blog.auth360.net/2014/01/07/first-impressions-ad-fs-and-window-server-2012-r2-part-ii/) is a nice overview of ADFS 2012 R2.

Comment: Ha almost a year later I see this answer :-) I will look into this :-)