# ADFS (3.0) integration with iPad app to achieve SSO implementation

Tags: ios, azure, adfs, adfs2.0

I am using **ADAL SDK**(https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) for integration my iOS app with ADFS for SSO implementation. I run demo code provide with above link.

As per as demo it's asking for following components to SOS implementation :-

1. clientId
2. Redirect URI
3. ResourceId
4. Authority Path

According to ADAL SDK ,I need to register my app to ADFS as per as this tutorial (https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/12/02/implementing-azure-active-directory-sso-single-sign-on-in-xamarin-ios-apps/).
**But i am not able to figured out how will register my app to ADFS**.

I also tried to figure out with this link ([loggin into an iOS app using a system with ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581677/loggin-into-an-ios-app-using-a-system-with-adfs)).

So the following question:-

1. Am i on right page?
2. If Yes, how to register and configure my app with ADFS
3. if No, please help to figure out this

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: did you get it working. I am looking for some configuration help as I am a newbie to this ADFS sort of thing. Can you please let me know about the configuration like how to add a native client to ADFS 3.0 Windows 2012 R2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After R&D, I am able to figure out how to get all points With ADFS.

1. Client Id    :- it's a GUID.You can generate Online as well as , Generate GUID(http://www.guidgen.com/)
2. Redirect URI :- it's something related with Bundle Identifier(com.compName.MyTestApp), So after adding urn, Redirect URI is looking like this. **Ex. @"urn:com.compName.MyTestApp"**.
3. ResourceId   :- it's same as redirect uri in my case.
4. Authority Path :- it's ADFS login path url basically to authenticate with ADFS and get Access token.  **EX @"https.//myServer.com/adfs";**

Note :- Please change URL Types as per as you bundle identifier in Info.plist file.

Some Link which helped me :-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531010.aspx

[SSO from ADAL in WPF Client to ADFS 3.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412805/sso-from-adal-in-wpf-client-to-adfs-3-0-on-windows-server-2012-r2?rq=1)

Hope it will help.

Comment: In your example, into Info.plist, what is the URL Schema that you have registered for your bundle identifier (com.compName.MyTestApp)? Have you connected to Azure Active Directory or Active Directory Federated Service?

Comment: @Chandan Did you use ADAL library itself for ADFS authentication ?

Comment: Yes, I used itself. @subin272

Answer (score 3):

ADFS is a very different beast to Azure AD.

ADFS 2.0 has no OAuth support. ADFS 3.0 has some OAuth support (No OpenID Connect, Web API only) and you have to use PowerShell.

Refer: [Securing a Web API with ADFS on WS2012 R2 Got Even Easier](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/) for an example. (Not iOS though - not aware of any iOS example.).

ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016 in preview) has much better support.

Comment: thank you, it really appreciated. I will look into this :-)

Comment: @nzpcmad Any update on this ? are there any iOS samples related to this available now ?

Comment: For ADFS 3.0? No - and there will probably never be because it's such a narrow implementation. Best to upgrade to ADFS 4.0.