# Authenticate iOS app against AD FS

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, adfs, adal

I am creating a iOS app which would authenticate against the AD FS. I am completely new to AD FS but have worked on Azure AD authenticate before. I tried using ADAL for it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181367/loggin-into-an-ios-app-using-adfs) but it does not work (maybe [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/222) reason)

```
var AuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(ServiceConstants.AUTHORITY, false);
AuthResult = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURL, ServiceConstants.CLIENTID, ServiceConstants.RETURNURI, param);
```

where Authority is something like https://sts.xxx.xx.xx.xx/adfs

How can I authenticate against the AD FS using Adal? or if there is any other method to achieve this in object C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works with ADFS that supports OAuth2. Any version that does not support it, will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any other way I can authenticate against AD FS then from a native mobile?

Comment: As I said above, yes you can using ADAL if ADFS supports OAuth2. Otherwise, you would need to write your flows.

Comment: The client is looking for providing with OAuth2 support. How can I implement the same if OAuth2 is supported?